# Could memory issues in Java cause a BufferedReader to return null prematurely?

Tags: java, memory

I have a program which reads data from an InputStream until a null is encountered. However, the program seems to not obtain all available data. Is it possible that a null is presented due to memory issues prematurely? I get not memory error but I do get files of different sizes and a much larger file was obtained when a change was made that may have freed memory. My plan is to run Java with options that give it much more memory.

Code:

```
while ((inputStr = streamReader.readLine()) != null){   
  doStuff();
}
```

Comment: Can you post code to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: I've never heard of that. Why not post your code, that might make this easier to debug.

Comment: @KickButtowski There is no mention of calling anything on a null value in the question.

Comment: @ejp I said that a general rule I guess

Comment: @KickButtowski You also said the question doesn't make sense., and you said that as a consequence of your remark about calling via a null value. It's wrong and it's irrelevant.

Comment: @KickButtowski Don't make personal remarks here. Just delete your irrelevant comments. That is to say all of them. You don't appear to understand your own posts, let alone anybody else's.

Comment: You stated that the question doesn't make sense., for a reason which isn't relevant here. Pointing out errors in comments happens all the time here. Please stop this. Don't clutter up this place

Comment: There is nothing to discuss. You have made numerous false claims, now including harassment. Just stop it.

Comment: I think if I had posted code in the first place things would have been more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could memory issues in Java cause a `BufferedReader` to return null prematurely?

No. You would get an `OutOfMemoryError,` not a premature null.

Comment: I should mention that I get further when I removed some debug code that may have freed memory.

Comment: Some questions. 1. What is the input source? 2. What processing do you do, and does it contain a break or return statement? 3. What is your evidence that you're not processing he whole stream? 4. Does it happen if you do nothing but the above code plus a line count?

Comment: we are reading from a url and the evidence that we are not getting all the data is not only that the supplier of the data says there is more but the variable size of the output files created from the data. The processing is basically, read a record, write a record. Have yet to try line count. No breaks or returns but are you getting at the the OutOfMemory error may get caught and I am mistaking it for a situation in which the null occurs? The simple experiment will be adding more memory.

Comment: You're barking up the wrong tree altogether with this memory issue. It doesn't work that way. Somewhere you removed or introduced a bug. Look harder.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in fact was a disk space issue that caused the file to close (when caught that was part of cleanup) -- no null was encountered. The disk space error did not show up because the write to a log file could not complete. Thanks for the "barking up the wrong tree" comment because indeed I was. I should add that this was complicated by the code running on Amazon Web Services.

I am sorry if I did not give enough info to the posters but as I said, the input was useful.